# (Swift)Tell me the reason why I cannot query the items

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
   var menuArray: [String] = []
      override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       fetchData {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
            print(self.menuArray)
       }
   }
```

```
      func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void){

      let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
      let saveDocument = Firestore.firestore()
      let uploadDocument = saveDocument.collection("Posts")

      let query = uploadDocument.whereField("LikeId", isEqualTo: user!.uid)

        query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in

         if error != nil {
                print("error")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                   if let menuValue = document.data()["Menu"] as? String{
                        self.menuArray.append(menuValue)
                        print(menuValue)
                        print(self.menuArray)

                    }}}}                  
            completion()
```

I don't know why print Items came out *[ ]*(nil)

Maybe query part are wrong,...
I use **whereField** to find **User!.uid**
I don't know the reason why this code are wrong.
please tell my the reason of this.

Answer (score 1):

`LikeId` is an array, you need to do the following to check if the array contains a value or not:

```
 let query = uploadDocument.whereField("LikeId",  arrayContains: user!.uid)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership